# PHP - $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

Tags: php

I am trying to build an application and I need to check the referrer URL which redirects to this page, the refered paged will not show... It works when it is a button but when the page otherwise redirects from another page, it remains blank.
How can I do this??

Comment: Are you able to provide a snippet of how your trying to save the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

Comment: <?php print $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; ?>

Answer (score 3):

It will/may be empty:

> - when the end-user entered the site URL in browser address bar itself.
> - visited the site by a browser-maintained bookmark.
> - visited the site as first page in the window/tab.
> - switched from a https URL to a http URL.
> - switched from a https URL to a different https URL.
> - has security software installed (antivirus/firewall/etc) which strips the referrer from all requests.
> - is behind a proxy which strips the referrer from all requests.
> - visited the site programmatically (like, curl) without setting the referrer header (searchbots!) by @BalusC

Also it means, you will not always have an referrer address. So you cannot trust the referrer address at all.

For example:

There is an small exploit that everyone can easily do it:

> Go to any website, and inject a form-code, send data from this site to another site, so the destiny site will receive data from the injected site and not from you.

Never trust referrer addresses. Using a **SESSION** will most likely be the better route to prevent cross site form submissions.

I recommend to read:

- [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie with value of the referrer url in the header that expires in 5 seconds  then Fetch it in the new script and redirect back to the referrer

Like this:

```
$current_url= base64_encode($url); //$url should point to the current url

setcookie("referrer",$current_url,time()+5);
```

Now you can get the stored url in your next script using:

```
$referrer= base64_decode($_COOKIE['referrer']);
```

And also redirect using:

```
header('Location: '.$referrer);
```